# Как асинхронно работать с 2мя сокетами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, asyncio

В питоне хочу сделать не блокирующую работу с 2мя сокетами. Для упрощения примера представим Proxy.

Пытаюсь на asincio реализовать.

Клиент_1 устанавливает соединение с сервером - получаю reader и writer. Сервер устанавливает новое соединение с внутренним процессом через файловый сокет (в данном проекте, но может понадобится и другие типы соединения).

Процесс может создавать запросы клиенту, а клиент к процессу.

Очень давно на втором питоне делал несколько тредов которые общались через multiprocessing.Queue. Эти схемы надо бы исключить потому как передача большого количества данных займет много оперативной памяти.

С клиента читаю 4 байта заголовка, и по размеру тело сообщения. Тело обрабатывается и отправляется к процессу.

С процесса читаю по мере поступления отдельные, их также надо перепаковать.

Запускаю читалки в циклах. Та что с клиента отрабатывает одно сообщение, а вторая продолжает дергать процесс. Такое чувство что второй блокирует первый и вставляет awaitы в LIFO, не давая первому читать сокет клиента.

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается? В чём у вас сложности? Если у вас конкретная какая-то программа с asyncio не работает, то создайте *минимальный* но полный пример кода, который демонстрирует проблему, явно опишите словами желаемое поведение и подробно шаг за шагом что у вас вместо этого получается. [mcve] Если вам это проще, то приведите рабочий "блокирующий" код и явно опишите чем он вас не устраивает (зачем вам нужна "не блокирующая работа") -- к примеру: хочу поддерживать более одного клиента или хочу поддерживать более 1000 одновременных клиентов. В сторону: потоки общую память имеют

Comment: проблема в блокировках пока ридер из одного сокета передает данные во второй, я не могу передать из второго в первый

Comment: Что значит "не могу"? Приведите код (как я выше указал) и опишите его поведение  в наблюдаемых терминах (то есть не *как* вы думаете он реализован, а *что* он должен делать (намерение) и что вы фактически видите -- добавьте вывод на экран, если необходимо).

Comment: передаю, но в сокете пусто)

Comment: на самом деле минимальный пример сделать сложно. нужно 2х клиентов написать чтоб они слали данные примерно в нужном виде.. а если приводить пример из реального мира то он не будет таким уж минимальным... ладно постараюсь изобразить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте попробуем реализовать асинхронность по классике =) Асинхронность в отличии от синхронности заключается в том, что для каждого соединения мы должны создать контекст: некую структуру данных, которая будет хранить состояние соединения, информацию о том, что сейчас происходит на этом соединении. Действия же с соединением (чтение, запись и т.д.) происходят только тогда, когда соединение к этому готово. Поэтому, ни одно действие не вызывает ожидания. Ожидания в таком дизайне становятся недопустимы, так как все обработчики будут ждать одного.

Когда-то давно мы в универе на сетевом программировании постигли дзен и обрели знание о методе `select`. Метод `select` предназначен для опроса блокирующих потоковых классов: стандартный ввод (*stdin*), запуск приложения с ожидание результата (*popen*), получение данных с сокета (*socket*). В *Python* она тоже есть и выглядит следующим образом:

```
readst,writest,errorst = select(rlist, wlist, xlist[ , timeout])
```

Вместо того, чтобы запускать отдельный поток для каждого прокси-соединения, программа "крутится" в цикле событий и ждет активности на каждом из соединений, перемещая данные всякий раз, когда соединение будет готово. Этот подход особенно подходит для программ, которые делают большое количество операций ввода-вывода.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import select
import socket
import sys
import os
import fcntl
import logging

USAGE = "usage: python selectproxy.py proxyhost:proxyport desthost:destport"

class ProxyConnection(object):

    # определим максимальный размер буфера
    MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

    # ProxyConnection - класс, который пересылает данные между клиентским и целевым сокетом

    def __init__(self,proxyserver,listensock,servaddr):
        self.proxyserver = proxyserver
        self.servaddr = servaddr    # адрес сервера

        # открываем сокеты
        self.clisock, self.cliaddr = listensock.accept() # ждем подключения клиента
        self.clisock.setblocking(0)             
        self.servsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # сокет сервера
        self.servsock.setblocking(0)

        # буферы для данных, полученных из сокета
        self.buffers = { self.clisock:bytes(), self.servsock:bytes() }           

        self.connected = False      # подключен ли серверный сокет?

        # регистрируем сокеты и разрешать операции чтения
        self.proxyserver.registerSocket(self.clisock,self)
        self.proxyserver.registerSocket(self.servsock,self)
        self.proxyserver.activateRead(self.clisock)
        self.proxyserver.activateRead(self.servsock)

    # метод, возвращающий сокет на «другом конце» соединения
    def other(self,socket):
        if socket == self.clisock:
            return self.servsock
        else:
            return self.clisock

    # подключаемся к серверу
    def connect(self):
        # мы должны использовать метод connect_ex, потому что соединение является асинхронным и не будет выполнено немедленно
        self.servsock.connect_ex(self.servaddr)

    # метод, читающий данные из сокета
    def readfrom(self,s):
        if s == self.servsock and not self.connected:
            self.proxyserver.connection_count += 1
            logging.getLogger("selectproxy") \
                .info("соединение с установлено %s, количество текущих соединений %d"%(str(self.cliaddr),self.proxyserver.connection_count))
            self.connected = True
            return

        # читаем из сокета
        capacity = ProxyConnection.MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - len(self.buffers[s])

        try:
            data = s.recv(capacity)
        except Exception as ex:
            data = b""

        # если чтение не удалось, закрываем сокет (это происходит, когда клиент или сервер закрывает соединение)
        if len(data) == 0:
            self.close()
            return

        self.buffers[s] += data
        self.proxyserver.activateWrite(self.other(s))

        # перестаем читать, если буфер полон
        capacity -= len(data)
        if capacity <= 0:
            self.proxyserver.deactivateRead(s)


    # метод, который пишет в сокет
    def writeto(self,s):
        # получаем буфер, содержащий данные для чтения
        buf = self.buffers[self.other(s)]

        try:

        # пишем его в сокет
            written = s.send(buf)
        except Exception as ex:
            self.close()
            return

        # удаляем записанные данные из буфера
        buf = buf[written:]
        self.buffers[self.other(s)] = buf

        if len(buf) == 0:
            self.proxyserver.deactivateWrite(s)  
        # разрешаем чтение, если все записали
        if written:
            self.proxyserver.activateRead(self.other(s))


    # метод, закрывающий соединение
    def close(self):
        for sock in [self.clisock,self.servsock]:
            if sock:
                self.proxyserver.deactivateRead(sock)
                self.proxyserver.deactivateWrite(sock)       
                sock.close()
                self.proxyserver.unregisterSocket(sock,self)

        self.proxyserver.connection_count -= 1
        logging.getLogger("selectproxy") \
                .info("соединение с %s разорвано, количество текущих соединений %d"%(self.cliaddr,self.proxyserver.connection_count))


class ProxyServer(object):

    def __init__(self,host,port,serverhost,serverport):
        self.address = (host,port)
        self.server = (serverhost,serverport)
        self.listensock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.listensock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.listensock.bind(self.address)
        self.listensock.listen(5)
        self.connections = {}               # словарь сокет <-> ProxyConnection
        self.readsockets = []               
        self.writesockets = []              
        self.allsockets = [self.listensock] 
        self.connection_count = 0           # количество активных соединений


    def run(self):
        loop = 0
        while True:
            # Блокировать до тех пор, пока в одном из сокетов не будет активности, тайм-аут каждые 60 секунд по умолчанию
            r, w, e = select.select(
                            [self.listensock]+self.readsockets, 
                            self.writesockets, 
                            self.allsockets,                            
                            60)
            loop += 1
            # обрабатываем любые чтения           
            for s in r:
                if s is self.listensock:
                    self.open()
                else:
                    if s in self.connections:
                        self.connections[s].readfrom(s)
            # обрабатываем запись
            for s in w:
                if s in self.connections:
                    self.connections[s].writeto(s)
            # обрабатываем ошибки
            for s in e:
                if s in self.connections:
                    self.connections[s].close()

        self.sock.close()
        self.sock = None

    def activateRead(self,sock):
        if not sock in self.readsockets:
            self.readsockets.append(sock)

    def deactivateRead(self,sock):
        if sock in self.readsockets:
            self.readsockets.remove(sock)

    def activateWrite(self,sock):
        if not sock in self.writesockets:
            self.writesockets.append(sock)

    def deactivateWrite(self,sock):
        if sock in self.writesockets:
            self.writesockets.remove(sock)

    def registerSocket(self,sock,conn):
        self.connections[sock] = conn
        self.allsockets.append(sock)

    def unregisterSocket(self,sock,conn):
        del self.connections[sock]
        self.allsockets.remove(sock)

    def open(self):    
        conn = ProxyConnection(self,self.listensock,self.server)
        conn.connect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        proxy = sys.argv[1].split(":")
        dest = sys.argv[2].split(":")
        proxyhost = proxy[0]
        proxyport = int(proxy[1])
        serverhost = dest[0]
        serverport = int(dest[1])
    except:    
        print(USAGE)
        sys.exit(-1)

    logger = logging.getLogger('selectproxy')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    hdlr = logging.StreamHandler()
    hdlr.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    hdlr.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
    logger.addHandler(hdlr)

    server = ProxyServer(proxyhost,proxyport,serverhost,serverport)
    server.run()
```